# How to bring a third-party content?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes, theming

Drupal 7.
There is a service, there will send the request, it returns an xml. With the handler present in human readable form. We bring a response variable. How to display the value of this variable on the page? 
I created a page with hook_menu:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['serch'] = array(
    'title' => 'Result',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_proc'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_proc($parms){

}
```

In the FORM API I have not found a suitable element.
If use it hook_page_alter, I don't know how apply to the content?

```
$page['content']['system_main']['pager']
$page['content']
$page['content']['system_main']
```

or something else....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [#markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute) property to display arbitrary data.

The function signature for your drupal_get_form callbacks must be:

```
function mymodule_proc($form, $form_state) {}
```

Concerning the response object that you want to render, I would need more information in order to help you.

Comment: I want to display in the region "content" data which are not in the database. Standard way to do this through the admin panel or standard modules does not work.